# How do I get IIS running on Windows 1709 (build 16299.15)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-10, auto-update, intranet

After updating to Windows 1709, Build 16299.15 - I tried to run my intranet app, which uses the local host.  However, when I put in the URL to that (or to any permutation of localhost:XXXX, I get

"Service Unavailable" and "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable".

Any idea on how to re-start the local host?  I opened up IIS Manager...

Comment: This qn will be better findable if u make IIS or build16299 the main tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd forgotten all about the "DefaultAppPool". That was the problem

Comment: You should mark Terry's answer as "the answer" since he helped you solve the problem and your answer doesn't actually add anything to other users having the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

1. Stop `W3SVC`
2. Delete all files in `wherever\inetpub\temp\appPools`
3. Start `W3SVC`

Comment: I'd forgotten all about the "DefaultAppPool".  That was the problem.

Comment: Thank you @Terry.. Actually u can give the commands too. I got the same issue and is solved